# How do I convert a string to camelcase

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, camelcasing

I am given a string which I have to convert to Camel Case and return the resulting value from my function, using calls in main.

// CaseMaker.h

```
    - (instancetype)initWithString:(NSString *)string;

    - (NSString *)process;

    @end
```

// main.m

```
    #import "CaseMaker.h"

    int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
  @autoreleasepool {
    CaseMaker *maker1 = [[CaseMaker alloc] initWithString:@"this is a string"];
    NSLog(@"%@", [maker1 process]);

    CaseMaker *maker2 = [[CaseMaker alloc] initWithString:@"loopy lighthouse"];
    NSLog(@"%@", [maker2 process]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I have been able to convert strings with white space to have uppercase characters, but I can't make the first character lowercase, also I am capitalizing single word strings which I do not want to do. Documentation for NSString hasn't helped as much as I'd hoped

.m

```
    - (NSString *)camelCaseFromString:(NSString *)input
    {
    return [[input capitalizedString]stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
    }
```

main

```
    CaseMaker *maker1 = [[CaseMaker alloc] camelCaseFromString:@"this is a string"];
    NSLog(@"%@", maker1);
    CaseMaker *maker2 = [[CaseMaker alloc] camelCaseFromString:@"loopy lighthouse"];
    NSLog(@"%@", maker2);
    CaseMaker *maker3 = [[CaseMaker alloc] camelCaseFromString:@"supercalifragalisticexpialidocious"];
    NSLog(@"%@", maker3);       
    CaseMaker *maker4 = [[CaseMaker alloc]camelCaseFromString:@"HELLO BRO"];
    NSLog(@"%@",maker4);
```

> thisIsAString
>   loopyLighthouse
>   supercalifragalisticexpialidocious

The above is the expected output for this assignment. I was google-fu-ing around to see how other people approached this, but couldn't really find anything, read a bit of objective c documentation for upper case/lower case methods of NSString and still mystified as to how I should proceed

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little NSString category that adds a `toCamelCase` method.

NSString+Util.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NSString(Util)

@property (readonly, copy) NSString *camelcaseString;

@end
```

NSString+Util.m:

```
#import "NSString+Util.h"

@implementation NSString(Util)

- (NSString *)camelcaseString {
    NSMutableString *res = [NSMutableString string];
    [[self componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString * _Nonnull string, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
        [res appendString:idx == 0 ? [string lowercaseString] : [string capitalizedString]];
    }];

    return [res copy];
}

@end
```

Usage:

```
NSLog(@"%@", @"this is a string".camelcaseString);
```

Output:

> thisIsAString

---

In Swift you can create an extension to `StringProtocol`:

```
extension StringProtocol {
    var camelcased: String {
        return components(separatedBy: " ").enumerated().map { $0 == 0 ? $1.lowercased() : $1.capitalized }.joined(separator: "")
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
print("this is a string".camelcased)
```

Comment: [typo] I think you might have missed an operation out of your pipeline in the Swift translation.

Comment: @CRD The Swift code gives the correct result. What am I missing?

Comment: The ObjC has a lower case operation in it

Comment: @CRD Good catch. Thanks. Fixed (both versions).